# How to crop an image using KineticJS and rectangles?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

I am using KineticJS to place images on a canvas. I then want to draw a rectangle over them and have the user be able to pinch resize the rectangle and then crop the image to those dimensions. I've got the rectangle showing up great, but on tap of the rectangle it doesn't crop the proper dimensions.

Can anyone tell me what is missing here?

```
$(document).on("tap", "#edit-menu-reccrop", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    var astroElement = stage.find("#" + localStorage.getItem("canvas_image_selected"));

    var adjWidth = astroElement[0].attrs.image.width * astroElement[0].attrs.scaleX;
    var adjHeight = astroElement[0].attrs.image.height * astroElement[0].attrs.scaleY;

    var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x:astroElement[0].attrs.x,
        y:astroElement[0].attrs.y,
        offsetX:adjWidth / 2,
        offsetY:adjHeight / 2,
        width:adjWidth,
        height:adjHeight,
        stroke:"blue",
        strokeWidth:4,
        draggable:true,
        id:'cropRect'
    });

    transImage(rect, false);

    layer.add(rect);
    stage.add(layer);

    hideManiMenu();

    rect.on("tap", function() {
        astroElement.crop({
            x:rect.attrs.x,
            y:rect.attrs.y,
            width:rect.attrs.width,
            height:rect.attrs.height
        });

        rect.remove();

        layer.draw();
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?